# How to use a 3rd party code without integrating into my own code ? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, interface

I want to use a 3rd party network asset for my Unity3d game.

**TL;DR :** What is the best solution to use an asset without really integrating the asset code into my own code for this reasons:

1. The asset is being updated regularly.
2. Maybe in the future i will want to change that network asset to my own\other solution.

My initial solution was to create an Interface called **INetworkProvider** which all network solutions will implement, create a class that will drive from the 3rd party class that will handle my requests to that object.

The problem is what happens when the 3rd party asset require a type which my code doesn't know about ?

In my example the **Init()** function of the interface **INetworkProvider** would work fine but the **ConnectToMaster()** function won't work because the type **SpecialParams** is not recognized by my **NetworkManager** class what do i have to do ?

Create the **SpecialParams** Type in the 3rd party drive class and pass it to the ConnectToMaster Function ?

*My Solution Example :*

The **INetworkProvider** interface that all network providers will implement

```
public interface INetworkProvider {
    void Init();
    void ConnectToMasterServer(string ip,int port,SpecialParams sp);
}
```

The class that will drive from the 3rd party asset and implement **INetworkProvider** :

```
public FirstProvider : NetworkAsset.API,INetworkProvider {

    public void Init()
    {
      // Do init
    }

    public new void ConnectToMasterServer(strin ip,int port,SpecialParams sp)
    {
        // 3rd party API requires SpecialParams Type
        API.ConnectToMasterServer (ip,port,sp);
    }
}
```

My **NetworkManager** that will use the provider interface and call Init and ConnectToMaster fucn

```
public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour {
      // Define which network providers we have
    public enum ProviderType { FirstProvider,SecondProvider }
    public ProviderType providerType;

    private static INetworkProvider provider;

    void Awake(){           // Unity awake function
        InitProvider ();
    }

    public void InitProvider()
    {
        switch (providerType) 
        {
            case ProviderType.FirstProvider:
                provider = gameObject.AddComponent<FirstProvider> ();
                break;

            case ProviderType.SecondProvider:
                provider = gameObject.AddComponent<SecondProvider> ();
                break;

            default: Debug.LogError ("Provider Script not found!");
                break;
        }
        provider.Init (); // would work fine
    }

    public void ConnectToMasterServer()
    {
        // error here because SpecialParams Type is not recognized here
        provider.ConnectToMasterServer ("127.0.0.1",6000,new SpecialParams); 
    }
}
```

Comment: *reflection* ...

Comment: Build wrapper for it. This is really easy. Just make a wrapper for the required functions such as connect, read, write and close. Reflection @L.B mentioned is slow and will be bad option when using network features in game engine.

Comment: @Programmer but what if the connect function of the 3rd party api expect a type which my Network manager don't know about ? 
does the wrapper class needs to create it ? 


For exmaple :     

1.3rd party api Function : `Connect(string ip,int port,Special Type)` 

2.Wrapper function will be : `Connect(string ip,int port)
{
   SpecialType sp = new SpecialType ();
   3rdPartyAPI.Connect(ip,port,sp);
} `

NetworkManager fucntion will be : `Connect() 
{
   wrapperInstance.Connect(ip,port);
}`

Comment: Create your own special class too then add a function that converts your special class to the 3rd party special class. You can also implement an  `implicit operator` that can be easily used to convert from your wrapper class into the 3rd party wrapper class. Although, I haven't seen a connect function that takes a class as parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer i will use a wrapper class for it.
By the way This is the original api function that i had trouble with : `PlayNow(string name, int maxPlayers, List<Property> properties,
            Action<string, int> joinCallback,
            Action<string, int> createSuccessCallback, Action<CreateGameRoomError> createErrorCallback)`
A Property is just a class with 2 strings : name,value so it will be easy to implement and the CreateGameRoomError callback returns a type which i can just invoke my own code at the wrapper class that invoke an error back to the networkmanager

Comment: That makes sense but what I said should still work. I wonder why you are not using Unity's uNet Networking System.

Comment: I'm using the Master Server Kit Asset which is based on Unity Networking. I use it to create my own game server and host it on a dedicated server.
That is why i wanted to create this wrapper class so that right now i will use that asset but maybe in the future i will write my own solution or just use uNet Networking directly and not through an asset

Comment: Use Proxy Design Pattern.